# Jquery ZeroClipboard or Zclip nothing in clipboard IE 8 and 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm using Jquery plugin ZClip or ZeroClipboard which copies content to the clipboard via a button or link. The data to copy and links/buttons to activate this are loaded using ajax which needs to use plugin, I attach the elements after they have loaded as so:

```
$('#ajaxbutton').live('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    success: function(msg){
      $('a.ajaxcopymulti').zclip({
         path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
         copy:function(){
         return $('p#ajaxdescription').text();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and in ajax.php for example:

```
<p id="ajaxdescription">Ajax description copied to clipboard</p>
<p><a href="#" id="ajaxcopy">Click here to copy the above text</a></p>
```

Works for all other browsers but IE 7 and IE 8. I get this error:

```
Unknown Runtime Error: ZeroClipboard.js, line 135 character 3
```

So in the plugin code I change:

```
this.div.innerHTML = this.getHTML(box.width, box.height);
```

to:

```
$(this.div).html( this.getHTML( box.width, box.height ) );
```

Which gets rid of the runtime error, but nothing appears to be copied into the clipboard for IE 7 and 8. Is anyone familiar enough with this to give some help? Thanks.

Comment: Found a work around in the end, I just told it to use     window.clipboardData.setData('Text',text); for IE 7 and 8 otherwise use zclip

Comment: Melon, can you explain how you did this? I don't understand your solution. I'm using ZeroClipboard with Datatables and TableTools, and have the exact same problem. It all works fine in FF but IE gives me the same problem you documented. I also found that wrapping the jQuery selector around the offending line as you show results in another error when closing the page.

Comment: I check to see if the user is using IE, if not I will load Zclip. If they are using IE I won't load Zclip and will use the function I created that contains window.clipboardData.setData('Text',text); where text is the parameter that contains the string you want to copy. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just make sure the adobe flash plugin is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found what's going wrong in my case. probably it will be the same problem as you expierience.

IE gives an error at this line

```
this.div.innerHTML = this.getHTML(box.width, box.height);
```

next line is

```
appendElem.appendChild(this.div);
```

here we append this.div to the element "appendElem". appendElem is an DOM object and depends from where you placed your html copy fields in your html code. to be precise it is the second level parent. the error is thrown when appendElem can't contain this.div as a child node. In my case my copy fields where in table cells. the appendELem is in this case a Row Object which obviously can not contain any divs (firefox is smart enough to clean up the code). I wrapped my copyfields in extra divs so appendElem will be a  DIV object. to know what object your appendElem is containing just add and alert function, like this:

```
    alert(appendElem);
    appendElem.appendChild(this.div);
```

hope this helps!

Kasper Taeymans

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The above worked to eliminate the error warning in the browser, but then it inadvertently led me to another problem, where I find the clipboard fails to copy in IE 8, not tested it for IE 7.  "Object doesn't support this property or 
method" error is triggered by the call to "this.movie.setText
( this.clipText );" within the zclip.js file. Judging by this link [link](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/issues/detail?id=39) it looks like it could be  a bug in flash

Comment: I didn't noticed this bug because I'm loading the zclip in a page overlay using ajax. Once you refresh the overlay and zclip are gone so I can't refresh the zclip stuff. So I guess this bug only appears when the refreshed page contains the zclip/embedded swf object.

Answer (score 2):

Also do make sure that your Browser is updated with Flash Plugin for it to work correctly.

Comment: This belongs in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Except that he has not enough reputation to post a comment

Answer (score 2):

I just met this problem, and has solved it. This is because of the improper html tag, the jquery plug-in will add a flash layer with the div, so make sure the html tag outermost layer is div, that is ok.