# jQuery zClip not working in UI dialog in Chrome and IE9 (works in FireFox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zclip

Following works in chrome, IE9 and Firefox on a .php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#copyLinkButton').zclip({
path: "js/zclip/zclip.swf",
copy: function(){
return $('#linkToCopy').html();
},
beforeCopy:function(){
},
afterCopy:function(){
//succes
}
});
});
```

But opening it in a Dialog, it only works in Firefox and IE9-compatible mode:

```
$('.open-lv-form').live({
click: function() {
//define link
var linkViewId = this.id;

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
cache: false,
url: "redirect.php",
data: "id="+linkViewId,
success: function(response){
$("#lv-form-content").html(response);
}
}); 

//open
$( "#lv-form" ).dialog( "open" );
return false;
}
});
```

Is it the way IE and Chrome handles the fields? Why will it work in Firefox and not in chrome and IE?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
IE9 (f12) says runtime error on zclip.min.js line 12 from character 3666, line says:

```
this.div.innerHTML=this.getHTML(c.width,c.height)}
```

Still no solution, keep trying :)

More info: [Jquery ZeroClipboard or Zclip nothing in clipboard IE 8 and 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682178/jquery-zeroclipboard-or-zclip-nothing-in-clipboard-ie-8-and-7)

**Update #2:**

Solved in IE to use this instead of zClip:

```
window.clipboardData.setData('text',item.url);
```

Now only Chrome is struggling. Seems there is a security feature in chrome that disables interaction with OS. Keep me informed!

Comment: Jquery does not support IE9. There might be a fix for chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with chrome by changing the `z-index` value on `zclip.js`

```
var zIndex = 99;
```

to

```
var zIndex = 1500;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well in IE9.  Clicking the flash to copy to clipboard would not function properly in IE.  I fixed this by adding a doctype to the page.  For me this fixed my issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

See the source code of jquery.zclip.js, you will find the following:

```
// float just above object, or zIndex 99 if dom element isn't set
var zIndex = 99;
if (this.domElement.style.zIndex) {
zIndex = parseInt(this.domElement.style.zIndex, 10) + 1;
}
```

so if set the zindex of the zclip div, you must set calling domelment's zindex, like this:

```
<a href="##" style="z-index:10000">copy to clipboard</a>
```

Hope to help you!